# How to convert a binary representation of a string back into a string?

Tags: java

I have a string that was converted to binary with Integer.toBinaryString() on each of its characters.  The binary string was then mangled a bit (random bit flips) and I'd like to convert it back into a string.  Are there any simple methods for this in java?

Comment: How did you convert a string to a binary string with Integer.toBinaryString()? The input to that method is an integer, not a string.

Comment: Take each character of the string, cast as an integer to get the ascii value, then use integer.tobinarystring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can easily do it using `Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)`.

In your case the radix is `2` so you just have to split your whole binary string in substrings of 8 chars each and use `Integer.parseInt(substring, 2)`. Then you convert them to characters and you concatenate them..

Comment: Interesting.  I've never seen this used before.  Similarly, would converting from hex be done with radix 16?  Or have I interpreted the use incorrectly?